# Extend from the spaces $L^2$ to the tempered distributions $\mathscr S'$

Tags: distribution-theory

Recall that $\mathscr S(\mathbb R) \subset L^2(\mathbb  R)$.
Assume the continous and bounded functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C, \,f \in C(\mathbb R), f(t) \not= 0$ only if $a \leq t \leq b$ and that $|f(t)| \leq 1$ for all $t$.

We define for all $x,y \in L^2(\mathbb R)$

\begin{equation}
Wf(t,\eta) = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}}
\!
f(t + \frac{\tau}{2})
\overline{ f(t - \frac{\tau}{2}) }
e^{-i2\pi \eta \cdot \tau} d\tau.
\end{equation}

We have a nonlinear mapping

\begin{equation}
(f \mapsto Wf) : L^2(\mathbb R) \to L^2(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R),
\end{equation}

where we extend the $L^2$ spaces without rigour onto the space of tempered distributions:

\begin{equation}
(f \mapsto Wf) : \mathscr S'(\mathbb R \to \mathscr S'(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R).
\end{equation}

Based on Vobo's answer. 
You need the theorem 5.1 by Treves Francois to prove the extension from the $L^2$ spaces onto the space of tempered distributions:

[image]

**How can you prove the extension by using Vobo's mentioned things?**

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather technical argument, let me give you a basic idea:

**Theorem**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be complete metric spaces, $D\subseteq X$ a dense subset, $f:D\to Y$ *uniformly* continuous. Then $f$ has a unique continuous extension to $X$, i.e. there is a unique continuous $g:X\to Y$ with $g(d)=f(d)$ for all $d\in D$.

The proof strategy for this is quite obvious: For $x\in X$ let $(d_n)_n$ be a sequence in $D$ converging to $x$. The uniformly continuous $f$ transforms the Cauchy sequence $(d_n)_n$ to a Cauchy sequence $(f(d_n))_n$. Now set $g(x):=\lim_n f(d_n)$ which exists and prove that this limit does not depend on the special sequence $(d_n)_n$.

In your case, let $X=\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}), Y=\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})$ and $D=L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Next step would be to prove the uniform continuity of $W$.

Unfortunately, $\mathcal{S'}$ is not a metric space. But luckily, the above theorem extends to complete topological vector spaces like $\mathcal{S}'$ with the same proof strategy. But talking about completeness or uniform continuity in non-metric spaces requires concepts like uniform spaces and this is - I would assume - beyond your scope.

So the main question is to show that your map $W$ is uniformly continuous with respect to the strong topology on $\mathcal{S}'$. This means:

Given a $0$-neighbourhood $U$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$, i.e. an $\varepsilon>0$, a bounded set $B_2\subset\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ - that is some $C_{\alpha,\beta}>0$ such that for all $\varphi\in B_2$ you have $\sup_x |x^\alpha D^\beta \varphi(x)| \leq C_{\alpha,\beta}$ - there is a $0$-neighbourhood $V$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ - that is some $\delta>0$ and a bounded set $B_1\subset\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ - such that
$$
f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\,\text{ with }\,\forall\psi\in B_1:  |\int_\mathbb{R} (f-g)(t) \psi(t) dt|<\delta \,\,[\text{i.e.}\, f-g\in V] \\
\implies \forall \varphi\in B_2: |\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (Wf(t,\eta)-Wg(t,\eta))\varphi(t,\eta) dtd\eta |<\varepsilon\,\,[\text{i.e.}\,  Wf-Wg\in U].
$$

I have the feeling that this is true, but I am not able to prove this - sorry.

Comment: Do you know any papers about this extension with uniform spaces and with respect to the strong topology on $\mathscr S'$?

Comment: The theorem 5.1 in F. Treves "Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions, and Kernels" proves the above theorem.

Comment: Hmmm, the completeness of $\mathcal{S}'$ you will find in the literature. But now you need to specify your map $W$ to allow us to prove the uniform continuity, which is probably the main task.

Comment: W is cross-Wigner or Wigner-Ville distribution. **Is it enough?**

Comment: Not at all. Please be as explicit as possible for a mathmatician. You need to say what $W(f)$ is for an $f\in L^2$.

Comment: As long as you cannot describe $W$ properly, this discussion is useless. Once again, you need to specify $W(f)$ for *every* $f\in L^2$.

Comment: I added explicitly the boundedness and the continuity. You can assume that all %f% are uniformly continuous. **Is this enough for all $f \in L^2$**?

Comment: Using wiki's [Wigner-Ville article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution), I may guess a relation to your $W(f)$. But I want you to state explicitly your function $W$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I added the explicit definition of the quasiprobability distribution to the body of the question.